# Please explain 'defaultdict' concept based on the below code

Tags: python

```
payload = {'format': 'json', 'per_page': '500', 'date':'1990:2016'}
r = requests.get('http://api.worldbank.org/v2/countries/br;cn;us/indicators/NY.GDP.MKTP.CD', params=payload)


from collections import defaultdict
data = defaultdict(list)

for entry in r.json()[1]:
    if data[entry['country']['value']]:
        data[entry['country']['value']][0].append(int(entry['date']))
        data[entry['country']['value']][1].append(float(entry['value']))       
    else: 
        data[entry['country']['value']] = [[],[]] 

print(data)
```

Do I understand correctly that the 'if' statement is 'False', as the dictionary is empty: '{'Brazil': [], 'China': [], 'United States': []})', therefore  'else:' executes first to allow appending?

Comment: Did you try reading e.g. https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict?

Comment: This is a pretty nonsensical use if a defaultdict, in fact it defeats the entire purpose, but yes, you seem to understand

Comment: The whole point of `defaultdict` is so you don't need to write an `if` statement to initialize the dictionary element.

Comment: Note only that, but the code seems wrong. When it initializes the new entry, it doesn't append the values from `entry`. So it skips the first entry for each `country/value` pair.

Comment: It should be `data[entry['country']['value']] = [[int(entry['date'])],[float(entry['value'])]]`

Comment: I have read python documentation and understood the concept based on the examples. Though, this example extracted from an Udacity course confused me. I also think, as @Barmar explained, that the 'if statement' skips the first value which adds to my confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your understanding seems correct, but the code is poor.

First, it's not really taking advantage of `defaultdict()`, which should obviate the need for the `if` test. It could just as easily use an ordinary dictionary, with the test

```
if entry['country']['value'] in data:
```

Second, when the entry is empty (because it's the default), it's creating the nested lists, but never adding the current entry of the loop to it.

The correct way to use `defaultdict()` here is with a callback function that creates the nested lists.

```
from collections import defaultdict
data = defaultdict(lambda: [[],[]])

for entry in r.json()[1]:
    data[entry['country']['value']][0].append(int(entry['date']))
    data[entry['country']['value']][1].append(float(entry['value']))       

print(data)
```

Comment: yep. ALthough, I would use `temp = data[entry['country']['value']]` just to clean things up a bit, or even `dates, values = data[entry['country']['value']]`

Comment: Thank you @Barmar. This removes my confusion and I should then conclude that the Udacity code is constructed poorly, if not wrongly.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I'd probably write it like that as well, but in this case I think there's educational value to maintaining as much of the original code structure as possible.